# Subtracting the two consecutive attribute values in attribute table (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, vector-layer

I need to calculate the difference in the attribute value between consecutive features:
[image]

Is it possible to perform the difference using Field Calculator in QGIS? I can think of acessing attribute using id as:

`attribute(get_feature_by_id('Reference', $id+1)) - attribute(get_feature_by_id('Reference', $id))`

But this results in NULL. Any tips to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
attributes(
    get_feature_by_id(
        'Layer_id',
        $id + 1
        )
    )['Reference'] - "Reference"
```

Replace `Layer_id` with the id of your layer.

Remember that the difference of the last feature can't be calculated this way because we are subtracting to the next features **Reference** field the value of the current feature reference field.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution using arrays:

```
with_variable('array_field',
              array_agg("Reference"),
                   @array_field[$id]-@array_field[$id-1]
              )
```